# Set empty value for ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time, zoneddatetime

I want to migrate this code from [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to its replacement, *java.time* ([JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).

Specifically I want to use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Old code:

```
DateTime startTime = new DateTime();
DateTime stopTime = new DateTime();

durationMilli = Math.max(1, (stopTime.getMillis() - startTime.getMillis()));
```

to

```
ZonedDateTime startTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime stopTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
    
durationMilli = Math.max(1, (stopTime.getMillis() - startTime.getMillis()));
```

I have the following questions.

How I can set `ZonedDateTime.now()` to empty value? As you can see `stopTime` should be empty.
Send issue is that method `getMillis` is missing. How I can get milliseconds?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see "`stopTime` should be empty" - what do you understand as "empty value" ?  || Last part of question: `Duration.between(start, end).toMillis()`

Comment: Please define what you mean by "empty value".

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

> How I can set ZonedDateTime.now() to empty value?

Do as you would do for an object reference of any other class. Either:

- `null`
- `Optional.empty`

> How I can get milliseconds?

```
myZonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

## Details

### Yes, `ZonedDateTime` replaces `DateTime`

The [`DateTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class in Joda-Time represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as viewed through a specific time zone.

`new org.joda.time.DateTime()` captures the current moment as seen in the current default time zone. It's equivalent in *java.time* is `ZonedDateTime.now()`.

### Make time zone explicit

By the way, I find it more clear to specify that you know and want the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)’s current default time zone. Like this: `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )` rather than rely implicitly on the default.

### Empty?

You said:

> As you can see stopTime should be empty.

No, I do not see that at all. Where in your code is there any kind of empty value?

A date-time object such as `ZonedDateTime` always has a value. Having a value is its job, specifically: representing a moment as seen through a time zone. So there is no "empty" value. If you want to represent having no known moment, use either:

- `null`
- `Optional`

… with [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) being recommended. See [Guide To Java 8 Optional](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) by baeldung.

```
Optional< ZonedDateTime > empty = Optional.empty();
```

#### Epoch reference as a placeholder

Alternatively, if you want to use a specific moment as a flag or placeholder, I would suggest using the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) defined in *java.time*: the first moment of 1970 with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

The [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class has a predefined constant for that value: [`Instant.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH).

### Adjusting between UTC and a time zone

You can adjust an `Instant` in UTC to a `ZonedDateTime` in a particular time zone.

```
Instant instant = Instant.EPOCH ;
ZoneId z = Zone.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

And go back again, moving from time zone to UTC (zero offset).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

### Count of milliseconds since epoch reference

You may interrogate the `Instant` object [for a count of milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli()) since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z. Be aware of possible data loss, as an `Instant` object may have microseconds or nanoseconds that you’ll be ignoring.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

And back the other direction:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

I recommend against tracking time as a count from epoch. Such numbers are meaningless to humans, as we cannot determine a moment from a mere integer number. That means errors can slip by unnoticed. And debugging is more difficult. Also, there is the [Y2K38 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Instead, when storing or exchanging date-time values textually, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a need to set `ZonedDateTime.now()` to empty value.
You can use `zonedDateTime.toInstant()` and then `instant.toEpochMilli()` to get it in milliseconds.